# What is the most accurate ; statement vs prepared statement

Tags: mysql, jsp, select, prepared-statement

I'm working on this jsp project, out counselor told us to use prepared statement  because it is safe from sql injection than statement. But he mentioned it in mysql record insertion state. 

wHEN i work with select mysql select query I usually used to statements. But as the new idea I preferred to prepared statement too. Both are working just fine. 

Still what is the best thing to do. 

**While using statement..**

```
   try{                     
   Resultset rs2 = dbCon.createStatement().executeQuery("select max(grn_id) from grn");
       if (rs2.first()) {
                         int grn_id = rs2.getInt(1);
       }
   catch(Exception e){
        e.printstacktrace();
    }
```

**While using prepared statement..**

```
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "select * from item where name=?";

    try {
        con = db.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
                            int grn_id = rs.getInt(1);
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printstacktrace();
     }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Neither is 'more accurate'. They both obey the same semantics.

Comment: @EJP but they say that prepared statements are good for security. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for an opinion. That is always a hard one:
Both statement (in the shown context!) and prepared statement are safe. Depending on your DBMS and settings of that, prepared statement has 1 benefit: 
The DBMS can recycle the prepared statement and its execution internally, saving you query preparation time (even when you re-create the statement every time). So when name is 1 or name is 2, it saves you time (in most cases). We are talking about 100s to a 10th of a second here.

When using the statement, it is only re-used when it is exactly the same (name=1) or in case of SQL Server it is translated to a "prepared" statement (parameter substitution is executed by SQL Server internally: This costs less time then determining the query plan, but might still cost you 1/10000 of a second every query). Oracle does something similar with those statements.

Where does the statement perform better then the prepared statement:
In certain cases the data distribution is such that for example name=1 gives you 1MLN results, in which case the optimizer chooses to use an index scan, however name=2 gives one result, in which an index lookup would be better, and the optimizer chooses that plan.
With a prepared statement it happens however that the first chosen plan is used for all consecutive executions, so then a range scan would also be used to lookup name=2, which is less quick then a normal lookup.